# Updating bootcamp without re-installing

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Now that the [10.8.3 update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5612) is out for Mountain Lion with Windows 8 support, I would like to update my existing Windows 8 installation (upgrade from 7) to have the new drivers without re-installing Windows.

Does the Apple tools in Windows handle the update or is there a process that I must follow?

The reason for wanting to update the drivers to get newer graphics drivers specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run boot camp on your Mac and download the updated Windows Support files. Once downloaded, install them on your Windows PC as you normally would.